# How to prove $g$ is bijection from $\mathbb{N}_{m-1}$ to $A\setminus C$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> **Question** let $A$ be set with $m$ elements and $C\subseteq A$ with $1$ element then $A\setminus C$ is set with $m-1$ element.

(Although question look so trivial but i am stuck in proving it via method of bijection)

**My attempt** since let $A$ be set with $m$ elements so there exists a bijection $f$ from $\mathbb{N}_m$ onto $A$ where $\mathbb{N}_m=\{1,2,...,m\}$. So that we enumerate the elements of $A$ as $A=\{a_1,...,a_m\}$. Now as $C$ is subset of $A$ with $1$ element, so that $C=\{a_k\}$ for some fix $k\in\{1,2,...,m\}$
Hence $A\setminus C=\{x:x\in A\text{,  But } x\not\in C\}=\{a_i: a_i≠a_k\}$.

Now define, $g:\mathbb{N}_{m-1}$ to $A\setminus C$ such that, $g(i)=f(i)$ when $1≤i<k$, and $g(i)=f(i+1)$ when $k≤i≤m-1$. 
Then **how do prove $g$ is injective and surjectuve**

Since if $p,q$ such that, $1≤p<k$ and $k≤q≤m-1$ then $g(p)=g(q)$ implies $f(p)=f(q+1)$ that implise $p=q+1$ but this **does not** implies $p=q$

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things are slightly simpler if we are more careful with our choice of bijection.

Say $C=\{c\}$.

Step 1: We find a bijection $f:\mathbb{N}_m\to A$ with $f(m)=c$. To do this, argue as follows: fix a bijection $g:\mathbb{N}_m\to A$. Since $c\in A$, there is a unique $k\in\mathbb{N}_m$ with $g(k)=c$. Now define $f:\mathbb{N}_m\to A$ as follows:
$$
f(i):=
\begin{cases}
c & i=m \\
g(m) & i=k \\
g(i) & o/w
\end{cases}
$$

You need to check that this works.

Step 2: If $f$ is as above, consider the restriction $h:\mathbb{N}_{m-1}\to A\setminus C$, $h(i)=f(i)$. Prove that $h$ is a bijection.

Comment: Sir further, what is problem with my attempt? Is there is something wrong in My attempt?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi Your attempt is not incorrect. It's merely a matter of presentation. By ensuring that the (unique) element of $C$ is the last one to be listed, there are less indices which need to be manipulated. To show that $h$ is injective, note that $h(i)=h(j)$ implies $f(i)=f(j)$ which in turn implies $i=j$. To show that it is surjective, if $x\in A\setminus C$, then, because $f$ is surjective, $x=f(i)$ for some $i\in \mathbb{N}_m$. Now, $x\neq c$ and $c=f(m)$, so $i\neq m$ by injectivity. But then $i\in \mathbb{N}_{m-1}$ and $x=f(i)=h(i)$.

Comment: Note also that $h$ is well defined in the sense that it really is a function with codomain $A\setminus C$, that is, $h(i)\in A\setminus C$ for all $i\in \mathbb{N}_{m-1}$. To see this, note that $i\in \mathbb{N}_{m-1}$ implies $f(i)\neq f(m)=c$, so $f(i)\in A\setminus C$.